# 'getDoc' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]
I'm trying to use firebase hooks with firebase 8.0.0
I keep getting this error : 'getDoc' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Edit: I've switched to Version 9.21.0 but now can't use firebase at all.
Here is the code for my firebase.js file. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level `getDoc` function was introduced in version 9  of the Firebase SDK. In version 8 and before, you'd use the something like `firebase.firestore().doc("path/to/your/doc").get()` to do the same.

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_1) in version 8 of the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: I switched to version 9 but now I am getting a problem with firebase. It says Module Not Found: Can't resolve 'firebase'. I think this is why I rolled back to firebase 8.0.0 in the first place. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I added this code and it appears to work :                                                                   
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';